# How to configure procfile, sidekiq.yml so that different sidekiq queues run on different dynos in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, procfile

I have 2 kinds of queues in Sidekiq: "default/low" - to cater web requests and "background_queue" - to run background processes like fetching tweets. 
I want to run "background_queue" workers on a different dyno, so that it doesn't block any web requests during that period.

My procfile looks like this.

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker:  bundle exec sidekiq
background_worker:  bundle exec sidekiq
```

I see that i have successfully created background worker dyno in heroku.

So, how do i run jobs on background_worker ?

Comment: The problem got resolved. The following changes in the procfile did the job for me:  
    `worker:  bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q low` `background_worker:  bundle exec sidekiq -q background_queue`
Added background_queue to sidekiq.yml with relevant priority.

Answer (score 4):

The problem got resolved. The following changes in the `procfile` did the job for me:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q low
background_worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q background_queue
```

Added background_queue to sidekiq.yml with relevant priority

Comment: Reference for the options: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options